# How to animate MKOverlayRenderer added in Mapview iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkoverlay

I have a mapview as shown below

[image]

The lines drawn in the map are using MKPolyline. I have used apple MapKit framework to display my map. My requirement is when the user selects the annotation on Polyline, the polyline should show direction as shown below

[image]

How can I show the animation in my map view? MKOverlayRenderer inherits from NSObject, It is not possible to animate using UIView Animation. I found some link [here](https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay) , its in objective C for iOS 7, IS it possible in swift to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MKOverlayRender inherits from NSObject. So it is not possible to add CAlayer to MKOverlayRenderer as explained in this [sample project](https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay). The steps I followed to get the following animation effect are

1. Subclass MKOverlayRenderer and add a custom image as overlay on the map

   class MapOverlayView: MKOverlayRenderer {

   ```
   var overlayImage: UIImage
   var angle: CGFloat

   init(overlay: MKOverlay, overlayImage:UIImage, angle: CGFloat) {
       self.overlayImage = overlayImage
       self.angle = angle
       super.init(overlay: overlay)
   }

   override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {

       let mapImage = overlayImage.cgImage
       let mapRect = rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)

       // Calculate centre point on which image should be rotated
       let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: mapRect.midX, y: mapRect.midY)

       let a = sqrt(pow(centerPoint.x, 2.0) + pow(centerPoint.y, 2.0))

       let sub1 = (centerPoint.y / a) * cos(angle / 2.0)
       let sub2 = (centerPoint.x / a) * sin(angle / 2.0)
       let deltaX = -2 * a * sin((0 - angle) / 2.0) * (sub1 + sub2)

       let sub3 = (centerPoint.x / a) * cos(angle / 2.0)
       let sub4 = (centerPoint.y / a) * sin(angle / 2.0)
       let deltaY = 2 * a * sin((0 - angle) / 2.0) * (sub3 - sub4)

       context.translateBy(x: deltaX, y: deltaY)
       context.rotate(by: angle)
       context.draw(mapImage!, in: mapRect)
   }
   ```

   }

   class MapOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay {

   ```
   var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
   var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect
   var identifier: String?

   init(identifier:String, coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rect: MKMapRect) {
       self.coordinate = coord
       self.boundingMapRect = rect
       self.identifier = identifier
   }
   ```

   }
2. Call a timer to change alpha value of added overlays

   var timer = Timer()
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.toggle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

Function to change alpha of overlay renderer

```
func changeAlphaValue(identifier: String) {
        let overlays = self.mapView.overlays
        let tag: String = identifier
        for overlay in overlays {
            if let overlay = overlay as? MapOverlay {
                let identifier = overlay.identifier
                if identifier == tag {
                    let renderer = mapView.renderer(for: overlay)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        renderer?.alpha = 1.0
                    }
                }
                else {
                    let renderer = mapView.renderer(for: overlay)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        renderer?.alpha = 0.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will give the following animation on map

[image]

The project is available on GitHub - [link](https://github.com/abin0992/AnimatedMapOverlay)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jhurray/iOS7AnimatedMapOverlay

Above link are useful for you Or below code.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddOverlayRenderers:(NSArray *)renderers
{
    // Iterate through all overlayRenderers
    for (MKOverlayRenderer *overlayRenderer in renderers)
    {
        // MKPolylineRenderer
        // Animate a 'fade'
        if ([overlayRenderer isKindOfClass:[MKPolylineRenderer class]])
        {
            // Get MKPolylineRenderer
            MKPolylineRenderer *polylineRenderer = (MKPolylineRenderer *)overlayRenderer;

            // Let's manually set alpha to 0
            polylineRenderer.alpha = 0.0f;

            // Animate it back to 1
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
                    polylineRenderer.alpha = 1.0f
                }];
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Its not working. When I add this function my mapview does not loads. Here is my Playground with the above function used. gist.github.com/abin0992/343f90833434bf8ece6e3c16bfd46bc2